# How can I purge a branch in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I am newbie dealing with mercurial. I did some mess trying on branches and now I want to "flat" all branches in just one "default"

```
josir@josir-desktop:~/bitbucket/campus$ hg branches
default                       27:f28e8d8773c6
15                            20:6b434f251b7e
```

branches has already been pushed to remote repo.

I want to purge all other branches discarding all changes on it. Reading those [tutorial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PruningDeadBranches), I could not identify the best option to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing is to just "close" the unwanted branches and leave them in peace:

```
hg update -r "branch('15')"
...
hg commit --close-branch
```

If you only have push/pull access to the remote repo, there's no way to remove changesets after you've pushed them. So close the branch and move on, or discard the bitbucket repo, clean the local one, and start over.

To clean up your local repo, if you have a big mess the easiest way is to pick a good revision (e.g., the tip of default, but you can choose an earlier one) and clone just that and all its ancestors:

```
hg clone -r <goodrev> messy-repo new-repo
```

[The documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PruningDeadBranches) (which you'd already cited) has a good explanation of this and several other branch-pruning options, but *none* of them are appropriate after you've pushed to a repository you don't control.

Comment: for branch with name 15 update to branch head have to be `hg up 15`

Comment: Oh? Indeed! :-) Still, maybe this syntax is needed for some of the branches the OP wants to close. It'll work if the branch name contains a colon, for example. (Of course one could also just give the revision number...)

Comment: Perhaps a link to [PruningDeadBranches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PruningDeadBranches) would be helpful?

Comment: Thanks for replying @davidmc24 but the link is exactly the same that I post on original question. The link gave several options: I didn't know which is the best one for my problem.

Comment: It works like a charm! But I didn't get the syntax detail: If I use 'hg update - 15', I didn't work. Only works with "branch('15')". Why?

Comment: I'm getting really crazy with mercurial... When I issue **hg branches**, branch 15 disapears. But when I comand **hg update** and press tab, it still show branch 15. What's the difference ? Or should I ask another stackoverflow question ?

Comment: Ah, right you are.  In that case, I'll just confirm that most-likely-to-work solution for this sort of situation is closing the branches, as @alexis answered.  If you (somehow) are fairly confident that the changes hadn't been pulled elsewhere, BitBucket supports stripping from the remote server if you have admin access.  In future versions of Mercurial, there may be a better solution available via the [Changeset Evolution](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChangesetEvolution) work in progress.

Comment: Josir, "15" looks like a revision number. `hg update 15` means "update to revision 15". (Obviously it's a very bad choice of branch name). The `branch()` notation is a way to unambiguously name a branch.

Comment: Once you close a branch, it won't show up with `hg branches`. I've no idea what's doing tab completion for you, but it's probably a `bash` feature and the expansion happens to include closed branches. You could change that behavior, but you have to read up on bash `autocomplete` and redefine the expansion-- it's got nothing to do with `hg`.

Comment: I found the problem! I will note it as an answer because here I can't format my results.

Answer (score 0):

For already pushed branch you haven't any freedom: only `--close-branch`

Answer (score 0):

When I issue **hg branches**, I got a two column report like the above:

```
josir@josir-desktop:~/bitbucket/spo$ hg branches
dev                          232:31cf2690dd47 (inativo)
```

What have I understood for that ?

There are 2 opened branches :(

That was my big mistake. **There is just ONE branch: dev**

The second column "232:31cf..." is just the last commit of the "dev" branch!!!